# MYSQL match against not showing same results as mysql like %% query

Tags: mysql

We just migrate our all mysql like %% queries to MATCH Against

Our old query waS

```
SELECT * from jobs where jobtitle like '%php%'
```

I tried following queries

```
SELECT * from jobs where MATCH(jobtitle) AGAINST ('php')
SELECT * from jobs where MATCH(jobtitle) AGAINST ('php'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I tried * + and all but none query show same exact results which show like '%php%'

I want mysql query using match against to find the word anywhere in job title

Comment: What is the MySQL version, you are using?

Comment: Describe the differences pls!

Comment: differences means? Just not showing same exact results

Comment: can you convert my this query 
SELECT * from jobs where jobtitle like '%php%' 
to match against?

but i want same results. i want it find php anywhere in jobtitle. also i think match is case sensetive

Comment: i am using mysql 5.6

Comment: @ArmanMalik check `ft_min_word_len` of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum and maximum lengths of words to be indexed are defined by the ft_min_word_len and ft_max_word_len system variables. The default minimum value is 4 characters. That is why it's not working with 3 characters.

You need to change its value, and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes. If you want three-character words to be searchable, you can set the ft_min_word_len variable by changing its value in the configuration file. Or, if you have super user permissions you can set this environment variable with:

```
SET  ft_min_word_len=3
```

Check for more details : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: but also it do not show same exact results like mysql like %% query

Comment: i got it. its working good. can u just tell me difference between IN BOOLEAN mode or without it? What is difference between normal match against or using with boolean

Answer (score 0):

In mysql v5.6 the default value of [ft_min_word_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) server variable is 4, which means that 'php' search string would not return any rows in the natural language mode and boolean mode, unless you lower the limit to 3 and recreate the fulltext indexes.

In natural language mode on myisam tables the query would not return any rows if the word php is present in more than 50% of the rows. So, use boolean mode with + operator.

Comment: can u give me example how you talking about use boolean mode with + operator

Comment: Come on, it's in your own question! '+php'

Comment: i got ur point but i notice that like %% and match show different results. using match show less results than match why this is so

Comment: Both answers suggested you to do sg else, not just simply change your query!

Comment: you mean if i use without Boolean mode then it will show results only if the word is in 50% of the rows

Comment: Less than 50%. Above 50% it is considered 'noise'.